# Find max number of concurrent events

Tags: bash, awk

I'd like to print the max number of concurrent events given the start time and end time of each event in "hhmm" format (example input below)

```
$ cat input.txt  
1030,1100 
1032,1100
1032,1033 
1033,1050 
1034,1054
1039,1043 
1040,1300
```

For this, I would

- Sort by start time (column 1)
- Use awk/sed to  iterate over all values in column 2 (i.e end time) to find the count of end times preceeding this event which are greater than the current value (i.e find all
  currently running events). To elaborate, assuming line 3 was being processed by awk ... Its end time is 10:33. The end times of the preceding 2 events are 11:00 and 11:00.
  Since both these values are greater than 10:33 (i.e. they are still running at 10:33), the third column (i.e. number of concurrent jobs) would contain 2 for this line

The expected output of the awk script to find concurrent events for this input would be

```
0
1
2
2
2
4
0
```

- Find the max value of this third column.

My awk is rudimentary at best and I am having difficulty implementing step 2.
I'd like this to be a pure script without resorting to a heavy weight language like java.
Hence any help from awk gurus would be highly appreciated. Any non-awk linux one liners are also most welcome.

Comment: I've updated the question. "current value" is the end time of the line currently being processed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN  {FS="\,"; i=0}

{ superpos=0;
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++ ){
      if($2 < a[j,2])
          ++superpos
     }
      a[++i,1]=$1;
      a[i,2]=$2;
      print superpos;
      a[i,3]=superpos;
}
END{ max=0; 
        for (j=1; j<=i; j++ ){ 
          if ( a[j,3]>max)
            max= a[j,3];
     }
     print "max = ",max;
 }
```

Running at [ideone](http://ideone.com/clone/SPE0L)

HTH!

Output:

```
0
0
2
2
2
4
0
max =  4
```

**Edit**

Or more awkish, if you prefer:

```
BEGIN  {FS="\,"; max=0 }
{ 
    b=0; 
    for (var in a){
      if($2 < a[var]) b++;
    }  
      a[NR]=$2;
      print b;
      if (b > max) max = b;
}
END { print "max = ", max }
```

Comment: gawk complains that it's unnecessary to escape the comma. The second output line should be 1 (the test should be `<=` instead of `<`). [ideone](http://ideone.com/GDaL0)

Comment: @Dennis the escaped comma is for campatability. The test is as requested *preceeding this event which are greater than the current value*

Comment: Adding for the record my own bash implementation which is more brute force and certainly cant be converted into a one-liner ...

end_times=
start_times=
geqs=
i=0
while read line ; do
    start_times[$i]=`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}'`
    end_times[$i]=`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2}'`
    geq=0
    for end_time in "${end_times[@]}"; do
        if [ $((end_time)) -ge $((end_times[$i])) ]; then
            let geq=$((geq + 1))
        fi
    done
    geqs[$i]=$geq
    let i=$((i + 1))
done

for (( c=0; c<i; c++ )) do
    echo $((start_times[$c])),$((end_times[$c])),$((geqs[$c]))
done